# How can I kill a python matplotlib script?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm starting to play around with image processing with python in linux. so I run the code

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('sample.jpg').convert('L'))

im2 = 255 - im
imshow(im)

figure()
imshow(im2)
figure()
im3 = (100.0/255)*im + 100
imshow(im3)
figure()
im4 = 255.0 * (im/255.0)**2
imshow(im4)
show()
```

I create 4 figures. when i close these figures and want to run another code, i get the message:

```
Already Executing:
The Python Shell window is already
executing a command; please wait unit it is finished.
```

I would have to close the python shell window to execute another command. is there anyway to properly kill execution so i don't have to close the python shell everytime to run another script?

Answer (score 0):

do you have the same problem if you add `exit()` at the end of the script (after the call to `show`)?

**Edit** on Unix you should be able to interrupt the execution of a program/script with ctrl+c

Comment: I should also mention that im working with IDLE. including exit just kills my scripts and won't even generate my figures. I'm also not able to use ctrl+c in the command shell as I don't have control of the window, otherwise there is no >>> in the window

Comment: if you work without interactivity, the call to `show()` should show the figures and block the script until they are closed. Only then it will execute the following command. What is the output of `isinteractive()`?

Answer (score 0):

Which Python shell are you using? This behaviour seems quite unusual. If you use `ipython` , you could try to run ipython with `-pylab`-option to avoid threading issues.

If you don't use ipython, please tell us which variant you are using. The `python`? Some IDE, like Spyder? It really depends.

I honestly recommend using ipython.

Comment: I should add that I'm using the IDLE environment.